# Create DISTINCT list of users from table with NULL values

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e9783268aeb85d9b03acc358fb60fe2a)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer VARCHAR(255),
    confirmed_date DATE,
    first_order DATE
);

INSERT INTO customers
(customer, confirmed_date, first_order)
VALUES 
('user_01', '2020-03-12', '2020-04-10'),
('user_01', NULL , '2020-04-10'),

('user_02', '2020-04-07', '2020-05-28'),
('user_03', '2020-05-19', '2020-05-22'),
('user_04', NULL, '2020-07-09'),

('user_05', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-04'),
('user_05', NULL , '2020-06-04'),

('user_06', '2020-07-18', '2020-10-23');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customer  |  confirmed_date |   first_order  |
----------|-----------------|----------------|------
user_01   |    2020-03-12   |   2020-04-10   |
user_02   |    2020-04-07   |   2020-05-28   |
user_03   |    2020-05-19   |   2020-05-22   |
user_04   |      NULL       |   2020-07-09   |
user_05   |    2020-06-03   |   2020-06-04   |
user_06   |    2020-07-18   |   2020-10-23   |
```

---

I want to list all `DISTINCT` users from the results in the table. 
However, the data inlcudes:

a) users that do not have any confirmed_date `(e.g. user_04)` 
b) users that appear with a row incl. a confirmed_date and another row without a confimred_date `(e.g. user_01, user_05)`

In case of a) I want to include the user with confirmed_date NULL. 
In case of b) I want to use the row which includes a confirmed_date

So far I came up with this query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT c.customer AS customer,
c.confirmed_date AS confirmed_date,
c.first_order AS first_order
FROM customers c
WHERE c.confirmed_date IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 1;
```

It almost provides the expected results but excludes `user_04`.

How do I need to modify it to get the correct results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you should be able to just aggregate by customer and then select the max value of the date and order columns:

```sql
SELECT customer, MAX(confirmed_date) AS confirmed_date, MAX(first_order) AS first_order
FROM customers
GROUP BY customer;
```

Just for reference, the `MAX` function (along with most other aggregate functions) ignore `NULL` values by default.  So taking the `MAX` here works well, because it disregards the missing dates and instead selects the non `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

The first "confirmed" or the only existing  row per a customer

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by customer order by confirmed_date) rn
  FROM customers c
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT ON`. The second `ORDER BY` expression will push records with non-null `first_order` up and include them in the selection correctly.

```sql
SELECT distinct on (customer) *
from customers
order by customer,
         case when confirmed_date is null then 1 else 0 end,
         confirmed_date;
```

The result is what you expect.